# Two codeigniter installation with tank auth login conflict

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, tankauth

Im having two codeigniter instalation , one is MERCHANT and the other one is CONSUMER.Both are having Tank Auth for authentication.But im finding problem in this.If im logged in the merchant side,the consumer will logouts and vise versa.Though this shouldn't happen since both are running as two different codeigniter installation with different tank auth libraries.But their sessions are conflicting each other and affecting each other.Even when I refresh the from MERCHANT side , it logs me in CONSUMER side ! Does some know why this is happenening ?

Comment: Does each CI install have a unique encryption key?

Comment: @Craig No.Its different

Comment: I just had a look through the Tank Auth code, you could change the name of the autologin cookie, in the tank_auth.php config file. Then, you could amend this line (https://github.com/TankAuth/Tank-Auth/blob/master/application/libraries/Tank_auth.php#L129) in one of your applications so it checks for a different userdata to login the user.